# How to statically link an existing linux executable?

Tags: c++, linux, executable, static-linking

Looking for a way to convert a dynamically linked executable to a static executable.  Seems like it should be possible but man pages are turning up short and google's not helping either.

Comment: Do you have the static libraries that you want to link against?

Comment: Yes, just don't have to source of the executable.